# Is it ok to load GA conversion script using jQuery .load()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

In the checkout process of an e-commerce site the same webpage is loaded for each step. However each step has an unique querystring value, e.g. `checkoutstep=confirmation`. In the final step I need to place a Google Analytics conversion script. I do this by dynamically  loading a HTML page containing the GA script using jQuery `.load()`:

```js
if (getParameterByName("checkoutstep") == "confirmation") {
    var placeholder = $('<div id="ga"/>').appendTo('body');
    $(placeholder).load('ga.html');
}
```

And the contents of `ga.html`:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = XXX;
    var google_conversion_language = "en";
    var google_conversion_format = "2";
    var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
    var google_conversion_label = "XXX";
    var google_conversion_value = 0;
    var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"></script>
<noscript>
    <div style="display:inline;">
        <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/XXX/?value=0&amp;label=XXX&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
    </div>
</noscript>
```

This *seems* to be working, but I know there are many things to consider. So my question is: is this a correct way to do? Is it ok to load the script using jQuery `.load()`?

Comment: I do not think that the GA script will run though

Comment: I tried to do e-commerce implementation this way, but it doesn't worked: Jquery loads HTML, but don't execute inner Javscript code.

Try to make javascript function for GA e-commerce tracking and call it instead of .load()

Comment: or just use the `<nonscript>` part

Comment: I do think it works. I added another script element (`helloworld.js`) after the `conversion.js` line and that file was executed (alert "hello world"). Or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Comment: well I guess you could use wireshark or something to confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GTM might do the trick, but there is another way: simply replace the tracking script with fake image request:

```
var imageAdwords = new Image(1,1); 
imageAdwords.src= "http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/982626378/?value=10&label=OLCXCK7ajgUQyuDG1AM&guid=ON&script=0";
```

Of course **use the values generated by your AdWords account**.

Comment: I do the image request. It feels safer somehow.